# Eclipse in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I am new in Ubuntu. First, I've installed `Eclipse 3.8` from the `Ubuntu software center`, but I don't want this version of eclipse. When I removed it and tried to install `Eclipse oxygen` from the `official Eclipse website`, I've faced the following error:

```
Version 1.7.0_131 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.
Version: 1.8 or greater is required.
```

I read on the internet how to fix it, but it appears it can't be fixed by myself.

Comment: You need to have Java 8 installed to run the current version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. install latest java 8 via ppa: [Guide how to install Java 8 JDK/JRE](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04).
2. download eclipse installer from official eclipse website. give permissions to that via `sudo chmod 775 ~/Downloads/eclipse installer name` and then launch script via `./.eclipse name you specified above`. If you everything correctly the gui installer will be launched.